# Ghost hunter story in Asimov's in the early 90s

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, ghost

This story takes place in the modern era - the main character can see ghosts, some of whom wander the world causing problems (in a manner I don't remember - temporarily possessing people perhaps, or something more subtle like making people feel miserable?). When the hero spots a troublesome ghost, he can with difficulty, pin them to one particular spot, so that they are considerably less dangerous- but he can still see and hear them (it's possible that they eventually (over decades) fade away).

Over the course of the story we see the hero deal with one ghost and then return home, exhausted - to the daily torment of seeing and hearing the ghost of his wife, whom he had pinned down in their bedroom a long time earlier. This ending is foreshadowed earlier when the hero passes a place where he had previously pinned a ghost and sees it still there.

Note - the trouble caused by ghosts is not due to malice - even a good person's ghost is dangerous to the living.

I do think this was in Asimov's, but I did occasionally read F&SF and Amazing back then.

Comment: How confident are you, individually, in the terms "ghost" and "pin?"  I'm not having much luck combining them, even beyond *Asimov's*.

Comment: Ghost could have been "spirit" i suppose - and there was probably some other term than "pinned" - sorry

Comment: It may be that he can only restrain the ghostsctobthe specific location they died.

Comment: TIL in Scandinavian folklore one way to dispell a ghost was to stake it to it's place of death.

Comment: Interesting- possibly an inspiration for the story

Comment: I agree, @Andrew, it's not Shottlebop,  I was too hasty. Shame on me.